# Two listeners on the same port?

Tags: windows, sockets

I was surprised to see netstat reporting two processes listening on the same port:

```
c:\Windows\System32>netstat -ao | find "8083"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8083           ***qa-w2k8-05:0        LISTENING       5532
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8083           ***qa-w2k8-05:0        LISTENING       1572
  TCP    [::]:8083              ***qa-w2k8-05:0        LISTENING       5532
  TCP    [::]:8083              ***qa-w2k8-05:0        LISTENING       1572

c:\Windows\System32>tasklist | find "5532"
java.exe                      5532 RDP-Tcp#0                  2  1,448,776 K

c:\Windows\System32>tasklist | find "1572"
FrameworkService.exe          1572 Services                   0     11,016 K
```

The Java process is my web server, FrameworkService is Mcafee. The http request does not even reach my server so I am assuming it reaches Mcafee. Shouldn't one of them get Bind error/Address already in use or some such error?

I am running Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, 6.1.7600 N/A Build 7600

Answer (score 3):

Generally you would be correct. However, there are options available to allow this sort of thing to happen. You may want to look at `SO_REUSEADDR` and how it affects behavior.

Basically, if you set `SO_REUSEADDR` another process can `bind` the socket. For more details on this (and the `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` option) check out the MSDN page titled [Using `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. This is most likely the reason. Not sure how I can work-around it though, hopefully there is some way to tell tomcat to bind with SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE.